# Bluetooth Scanning always available option in marshmallow

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-6.0-marshmallow

Hey I have researched about it a lot but could not get the answer.

What I want to do is I want to scan for nearby bluetooth devices even when bluetooth is turned off.

In marshmallow Android has provided this feature Bluetooth scanning and it is written there, it allows to scan and connect ot bluetooth devices even when bluetooth is turned off..
Can anyone help me with this? How to scan for nearby bluetooth devices even when bluetooth is turned off?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Bluetooth for finding nearby devices.How can you find nearby device without starting bluetooth.

Comment: But there is an option under Bluetooth section and then under Improve Accuracy Settings, "Bluetooth Scanning".
Its descripton says : "Improve location accuracy by allowing apps and services to scan for and connect to nearby devices automatically via Bluetooth, even while Bluetooth is turned off."

What does this mean? And if its possible how to get the scanning result from here?